# Extracting rows that meet certain criteria from a worksheet and populating another worksheet dynamically using functions

Tags: aspose-cells

My first worksheet has smart markers.The column names can be different each time.

Can I populate a fresh worksheet with only those rows that meet a given criteria on one or more of the columns?

Example: If the columns are TYPE and VALUE. Can I add only rows which have TYPE= A to another sheet.

I have tried autofilter but it requires knowing column index and my column names change from time to time.

I am using aspose.cells for java.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to cope with your scenario/case is you should filter and extract your desired rows/records in your query (e.g SQL statement) or ResultSet from data source by yourself, so once the Smart Markers are processed, you should have your desired data filled into the cells for your needs.